# ToroPHP Router in nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I am hosting ToroPHP in `/api/`. My `/api/.htaccess` was

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This worked great. I converted this to the nginx equivalent which got me roughly this:

> rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 last;

But this isn't working. What should the nginx equivalent be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question really belongs on http://serverfault.com, nonetheless:

### Use try files

Rewriting isn't necessary, the desired results can be achieved more efficiently using [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files):

```
server {
    ...


    location /api {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ index.php$uri;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

}
```

}

Note that it's not necessary to pass the url as an argument to `index.php` as it's already available as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (will require trivial modifications to index.php to work).

Comment: I added this. `/api/comments/?object=32&object_type=1` causes a 404. `index.php` already uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

```
location /api {
     try_files $uri $uri/ index.php$request_uri; # or /api/index.php$request_uri
}
```